# Shell: two loops over coomandline parameters

Tags: bash, shell

In a shell-script I have a loop over the positional parameters using the shift-command. After the loop I d like to reset and start another loop over the parameters. Is it possible to go back to start?

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
  case "$1" in
    "--bla")
      doing sth
      shift 2
      ;;
    *)
      shift 1
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can save arguments in a temporary array. Then restore positional arguments from it.

```
args=("$@")  # save

while .....
done

set -- "${args[@]}"  # restore
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `shift` if you need to process the arguments twice.  Use a `for` loop, twice:

```
for arg in "$@"
do
    …
done
```

If you need to process argument options, consider using the GNU version of `getopt` (rather than the Bash built-in `getopts` because that only handles short options).  See [Using getopts in bash shell script to get long and short command line options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/00402377/15168) for many details on how to do that.